# socket programming using bufferedreader

Tags: java

In my application I have 2 programmes, called `server.java` and `client.java`, `server.java` acts as a server and `client.java` acts as a client.
From `server.java`, I am writing some data to `client.java`, by using the following code:

```
bufferedwriter.write(data);
bufferedwriter.flush();
```

to read the above data in client i have written the below code:

```
if(bufferedreader.ready())
while((a=in.read)!= -1)
```

I am able to receive data from server to client,but the problem is whenever I kept a breakpoint at `BufferedWriter`. flush in `server.java` programme and `if(bufferedreader.ready())` of client.java,it is not going to intented destination (i.e, in my application intended destination is `if(bufferedreader.ready())` of `client.java`), but whenever I am closing `server.java` debugging, the debugging point in client programme is enabling, can you please help me to solve this.

Comment: you are using mark on stream ?

Comment: thanks for your reply Arpit,i am not using any mark,is it compulsory to use,if yes how to use and where to use in my application, can you please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible that your IDE blocks all threads at breakpoint. Could you please check debug settings. In Intellij IDEA it would be simple **Right click on breakpoint -> Suspend, Thread**

Comment: thanks for your reply mudalov, i am using netbeans as IDE how can i set in this netbeans

Comment: Haven't used it for a while, but take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174408/does-a-breakpoint-halt-all-threads) for Netbeans related details.