# ListView filter: IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, listview, filter, illegalstateexception

For the sake of sanity I am posting this here, because I am sure I cannot solve it on my own now. I am posting everything there is to know, because I think why I got no solution to this problem in the past is because I did not post everything. I have stripped the code so far that basically it is as light as it can get. But still this error occurs (although very very very rarely):

```
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929): The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class de.innosoft.android.mobileserviceclient.activities.ListEinsaetze$ArrayAdapterEinsatz)]
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class de.innosoft.android.mobileserviceclient.activities.ListEinsaetze$ArrayAdapterEinsatz)]
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.widget.AdapterView.updateEmptyStatus(AdapterView.java:747)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:720)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:812)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:5958)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at de.innosoft.android.mobileserviceclient.ui.DynamicArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(DynamicArrayAdapter.java:291)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at de.innosoft.android.mobileserviceclient.ui.DynamicArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(DynamicArrayAdapter.java:268)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at de.innosoft.android.mobileserviceclient.ui.DynamicArrayAdapter$DynamicAdapterFilter.publishResults(DynamicArrayAdapter.java:119)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-27 10:57:27.783: E/java.lang.IllegalStateException(4929):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

At the very bottom of this post I explain WHEN this error occurs. But first, the code. I have this TextWatcher:

```
edSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }

                String text = null;

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    text = s.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
                    if (text != null && !text.equals(s.toString())) {
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                    }
                    text = null;
                }
            });
```

This thread is run on the sideline to trigger the textwatcher every 200 milliseconds. I'd be crazy to test this manually:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                         KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S));
                         dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                         KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S));
                    }
                };

                Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                         KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
                         dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                         KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
                    }
                };
                while (true) {

                    runOnUiThread(r);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(r2);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

This is my Adapter:

```
private class ArrayAdapterEinsatz extends DynamicArrayAdapter<Einsatz> {

        public ArrayAdapterEinsatz(int textViewResourceId) {
            super(ListEinsaetze.this, textViewResourceId, new ArrayList<Einsatz>());
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Einsatz einsatz = getFilteredItems().get(position);

            View rowView = convertView;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ListEinsaetze.this.getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eintrag_einsatz, null);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.tvId = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eeinsatzid);
                viewHolder.tvDatumVonbis = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eeinsatzvonbis);
                viewHolder.tvKundenName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eeinsatzkundenname);
                viewHolder.tvKundenOrt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eeinsatzort);
                viewHolder.tvEntfernung = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eeinsatzentfernung);
                viewHolder.iveRotate = (ImageViewEffects) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eeinsatzrotate);
                viewHolder.iveRotate.setBitmap(Utils.drawableToBitmap(R.drawable.ic_refresh_1, 22), ImageViewEffects.ROTATE);
                viewHolder.ivAnsprechpartnerVorhanden = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eeinsatzimageansprechvorhanden);
                viewHolder.ivBelegeVorhanden = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eeinsatzimagebelegevorhanden);
                viewHolder.ivTaetigkeitVorhanden = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eeinsatzimagetaetigkeitvorhanden);

                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }

            final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

            return rowView;
        }

    }
```

And finally this is the base adapter class. Notice the actually filter function at the very bottom, it filters according to new Random().nextBoolean() which cannot be any simpler.

```
public class DynamicArrayAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

  public class DynamicAdapterFilter extends Filter {

    private CharSequence m_Filter = null;
    private List<T> m_FilteredItems = null;

    public DynamicAdapterFilter() {
      m_FilteredItems = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {


      FilterResults r = new FilterResults();
      List<T> items = null;
      m_Filter = constraint;

      if (constraint == null) {
        items = m_AllItems;
      } else {
        items = m_FilteredItems;
        items.clear();

        synchronized (SyncLock) {
          List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>(m_AllItems);
          for (T item : l) {
            if (DynamicArrayAdapter.this.filter(item, constraint)) {
              items.add(item);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      r.values = items;
      r.count = items.size();

      return r;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

      m_Items = (List<T>) results.values;

      notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void refresh() {
      if (m_Filter != null) {

        filter(m_Filter);
      }
    }

    public void refresh(FilterListener listener) {
      if (m_Filter != null ) {

        filter(m_Filter, listener);
      }
    }
  }


  private final Object SyncLock = new Object();
  private Context m_Context = null;
  private LayoutInflater m_Inflater = null;
  private int m_DelegateResourceId;
  private boolean m_ChangeNotificationsEnabled = true;
  private List<T> m_AllItems = null;
  private List<T> m_Items = null;
  private DynamicAdapterFilter m_Filter = null;


  public DynamicArrayAdapter(Context context, int delegateResourceId) {
    this(context, delegateResourceId, new ArrayList<T>());
  }

  public DynamicArrayAdapter(Context context, int delegateResourceId, List<T> items) {
    m_Context = context;
    m_DelegateResourceId = delegateResourceId;
    initItems(items);

    m_Inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  }

  public void initItems(List<T> items) {
    m_AllItems = m_Items = items;
  }

  /**
   * returns the filtered item count (or all item count if no filter exists)
   */
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
        return m_Items != null ? m_Items.size() : 0;
  }

  /**
   * returns the item at the position in the filtered list (or all item count if
   * no filter exists)
   */
  @Override
  public T getItem(int position) {
    return m_Items.get(position);
  }

  /**
   * holt position von item, exakte gleiche implementation wie ArrayAdapter<T>
   * 
   * @param item
   * @return
   */
  public int getPosition(T item) {
    return m_Items.indexOf(item);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
  }

  /**
   * returns the list view item delegate view. this view is inflated if it isn't
   * already inflated. Override this method to perform custom view operations
   * for the list view item.
   */
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = m_Inflater.inflate(m_DelegateResourceId, parent, false);
    }

    return convertView;
  }

  /**
   * returns the filter. this filter is created if it hasn't yet been created.
   */
  @Override
  public DynamicAdapterFilter getFilter() {
    if (m_Filter == null) {
      m_Filter = new DynamicAdapterFilter();
    }

    return m_Filter;
  }

  /**
   * If notifications are enabled, this notifies the base adapter that the
   * backing data has changed
   */
  @Override
  public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    notifyDataSetChanged(false);
  }

  /**
   * If forced or notifications are enabled, this notifies the base adapter that
   * the backing data has changed
   * 
   * @param force
   *          force notify even if notifications are disabled
   */
  public void notifyDataSetChanged(boolean force) {
    if (force || m_ChangeNotificationsEnabled) {

      super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }

  /**
   * @return UI context
   */
  public Context getContext() {
    return m_Context;
  }

  /**
   * @return UI inflater
   */
  public LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater() {
    return m_Inflater;
  }

  /**
   * @return Layout ID of the list view item delegate
   */
  public int getDelegateResourceId() {
    return m_DelegateResourceId;
  }

  /**
   * @return true if notifications are enabled, false otherwise
   */
  public boolean getChangeNotificationsEnabled() {
    return m_ChangeNotificationsEnabled;
  }

  /**
   * Set whether notifications are enabled or not
   */
  public void setChangeNotificationsEnabled(boolean value) {
    m_ChangeNotificationsEnabled = value;
  }

  // internal mechanism to handle automagical updates of the list items
  private void onDataChange() {


    if (m_Filter == null) {
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
      m_Filter.refresh();
    }
  }

  /**
   * @return All (unfiltered) items
   */
  public List<T> getAllItems() {
    return m_AllItems;
  }

  /**
   * Set the backing list
   */
  public void setAllItems(List<T> value) {
    m_AllItems = value;

    onDataChange();
  }

  /**
   * @return Current filtered items, or all items if there is no filter
   */
  public List<T> getFilteredItems() {
    return m_Items;
  }

  public void add(T item) {
    synchronized (SyncLock) {
      m_AllItems.add(item);
    }

    onDataChange();
  }

  public void insert(T item, int index) {
    synchronized (SyncLock) {
      m_AllItems.add(index, item);
    }

    onDataChange();
  }

  public void remove(T item) {
    synchronized (SyncLock) {
      m_AllItems.remove(item);
    }

    onDataChange();
  }

  public void removeAt(int index) {
    synchronized (SyncLock) {
      m_AllItems.remove(index);
    }

    onDataChange();
  }

  public void clear() {
    synchronized (SyncLock) {
      m_AllItems.clear();
    }

    onDataChange();
  }

  public void sort(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    synchronized (SyncLock) {
      Collections.sort(m_Items, comparator);
    }

    onDataChange();
  }

  protected boolean filter(T item, CharSequence constraint) { // AR
    return new Random().nextBoolean();

  }
}
```

So basically the program just triggers the textwatcher every 200 ms. So the textwatcher filters the list again and again. Nothing else is happining in the program.

If I set no breakpoint the program just runs fine with no error always.

The error occurs when I breakpoint the line

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
```

in the TextWatcher and hold F8 (continue) pressed (this seems to bring irregularity into the program flow, I can only imagine?). Without breakpoint no error occurs.

And BTW if I put

```
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
```

after

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
```

the same error will occur 100% of the time (I know notifyDatasetChanged is called in publishResults, so I don
t need it, but is it nonetheless correct behaviour?).

**TL;DR:**

Is my code (especially the base adapter code) failsafe? (well can't be else no errors would occur)

**EDIT:**

error also occurs when no breakpoint is set I just got one...

Comment: This code is running on multiple threads so when you break-point that line my guess is that it will pause this thread while the others are running resulting in this error. As for the  adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() method beilg placed after the adapter.getFilter method I can only speculate that something similar is happening. I don't know anything about android development so I'm just guessing here...

Comment: Hm I strongly believe the debugger halts all threads (= entire program) when it encounters a breakpoint.

Comment: *If I set no breakpoint the program just runs fine with no error always.* and *error also occurs when no breakpoint is set I just got one...* this two sentences seem contradictory. Did you at least tried to make copies of the data in the performFiltering method like I've recommended you on the previous question?

Comment: No they do not contradict each other. My edit is correct. It is just hard to know when the error occurs, so I did an edit and clarified as soon as I saw the error occurs also without any breakpoint. You can filter 1000 or 1000000 times and no error occurs and then it happens... Also I now added List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>(m_AllItems); after the synchronized in the performFiltering. still error occurs.

Comment: @cdbeelala89 No it don't, well at least not on web containers may be there's a switch somewhere..

Comment: Yep see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174408/does-a-breakpoint-halt-all-threads

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your

```
 adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
```

line in to ui thread with view.post() in a runnable.

it "may" solve your problem.

Comment: post is a method of view.It posts a single runnable to ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

Dont add a textwatcher instead just set the adapter to the edit text like below.

edSearch.setAdapter(adapter);

And override the public Filter getFilter() and
protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results)
methods.

This will take care of your problem..Faced the same problem and had solved it this way :)