# Spring Boot Async method blocking

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I am trying to save a document from a spring controller asynchronously. Since it can often fail I want to I have the following method on a service ran asynchronously so I can repeat the call. The UI client doesn't need to wait for it to complete.

```
@Service
public class AsyncService {

    @Autowired
    DocumentClient documentClient;

    @Async
    public void save(Document document)  {

        int tryCount = 0;
        while (tryCount < RETRY_LIMIT) {
            try {
                tryCount++;
                documentClient.save(document);
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (tryCount < RETRY_LIMIT) {
                    log.info("Retrying save document");              
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint at line `documentClient.save(document);` it is blocking and the controller is waiting. But when I set a breakpoint at "return" the call is executed async and the controller returns while I'm still paused at the breakpoint. Any ideas why this happens? I thought the whole method `save(Document document)` would be non-blocking.

I'm using Springboot 1.5 and Intellij as a debugger/runtime.

Comment: The breakpoint will cause all threads to pause at that moment. So when it kicks in everything pauses. So when setting it at the save, it pauses the main executing thread as well.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175107/10368507)

Comment: Maybe you have forgotten to annotate the main class with @EnableAsync.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij by default suspends all threads. It can be configured on the breakpoint to suspend only the current thread and that solves the issue. Thanks you @M.Deinum for the answer.